# Any way to compare two pytorch Tensor objects in two different python programs?

Tags: python, pytorch, md5, bin

I'm debugging two Python programs and both of them have a variable `img` (specific type is `torch.Tensor`), now I need to make sure if the two `img`s are binary-consistent. Because they are in different programs, I cannot compare them directly using my debugger.

The only way I've found is to dump them to local file and then compare them by loading to the same program or just using some tools like beyondcompare. But I feel this method is too inconvenient.

Is there any way like `md5sum` i.e. generating a unique identifier only decided by binary info of a variable in memory (so that I can just compare the two identifiers intuitively through they are in different programs)? Or some way else more convenient?

Comment: If you know how, the MD5 checksum sounds like a good idea. You'd need to modify both programs to `import hashlib` and call `hashlib.md5(binary).hexdigest()` (probably use a more modern hash like SHA1 or SHA256 unless you are extremely strapped for cycles). Your question doesn't contain enough information to determine whether this is acceptable. You could do this from within a debugger, too.

Comment: Good that helps! P.S. `pickle.dumps` can transform variables to bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing my response based on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-variables-from-another-file-in-python)

Assuming your two program files are in the same package, you can try importing one of the program files into the other by adding `import programName` with programName being the name of the other program but without .py at the end.

Then, you can declare a variable that will store the `img` variable from the other program by doing something like `imgOther = programName.img`

Now I think you should be able to compare `img` to `imgOther` and achieve what you were going for.

Comment: Thanks but seems still not convenient because most times the variable is in a function, we can't directly read it by `import`.